# JSlint в Brackets - научить понимать for in

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint, brackets

Можно ли как-то научить JSlint понимать нормальный javascript, главная проблема это **for in**, в который он упирается и не сканирует дальше даже если *maxerr* поднять до 10, пробовал сделать

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
```

и

```
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

,но он всёравно в него упирается.
Код стандартный

```
var array = [];
for (i in array) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Ну или надо отключать ошибку

```
Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function
```

тогда можно делать так

```
var array = [];
for (var i in array) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода, на котором JSLint сходит с ума.

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: jslint советует вообще обходиться без `for` - в данном случае лучше использовать функции массива, например _forEach_, для объектов советуют брать ключи с помощью _Object.keys_ и далее на полученном массиве использовать функции массива. В справке по JSLint, конструкции для игнорирования ошибок - отсутствуют

Comment: я знаю что она отсутствует, но может быть можно обойти остановку сканера или игнорирование этого участка кода, хотя всё больше понимаю что от глючного Brackets надо избавляться

Comment: Избавляться надо от `for`..`in` для массивов, [и вот почему](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). :)

Comment: @vnn198, скорее избавляться надо от использования конструкции `for..in`

Comment: для меня это плюс а не проблема, ибо пустые массивы мне обрабатывать ненадо

Comment: пустые массивы и так бы пропутились